# password cannot contain british pound in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, frameworks, encoding, passwords

Have I discovered a bug in the .NET framework or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the story.

I was trying to set a password on the WCF channel yesterday like that:

```
channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = credentials.Username;
channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = credentials.Password;
```

and then invoke the web service method when I got this error:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
   Message=An error (The request was aborted: The request was canceled.) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel.
   Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
     Server stack trace: 
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
     Exception rethrown at [0]: 
        at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
        at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
        at PocketKings.Tools.Services.PopulationManager.Client.PopulationService.IPopulationService.ResolvePopulationMember(ResolveRealmMemberQuery request)
   InnerException: System.Net.WebException
        Message=The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
        Source=System
        StackTrace:
             at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
             at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
        InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
             Message=This method is not supported by this class.
             Source=System
             StackTrace:
                  at System.Net.BasicClient.EncodingRightGetBytes(String rawString)
                  at System.Net.BasicClient.Lookup(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials credentials)
                  at System.Net.BasicClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials)
                  at System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
                  at System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)
                  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()
                  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e)
                  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DoSubmitRequestProcessing(Exception& exception)
                  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse()
                  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(CoreResponseData coreResponseData)
```

So i started looking at it and the logs show that I don't even get as far as the server. It turns out that the .NET framework method, which throws an exception (System.Net.BasicClient.EncodingRightGetBytes(String rawString)) doesn't like the british pound sign (£).

I copied the method from the reflector and wrote a quick unit test and pound is the only character that it doesnt like from all I could type on a keyboard:

```
    internal static byte[] EncodingRightGetBytes(string rawString)
    {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rawString);
            string strB = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);

            if (string.Compare(rawString, strB, StringComparison.Ordinal) != 0)
        {
            throw ExceptionHelper.MethodNotSupportedException;
        }
        return bytes;
}
```

This is my unit test to check this method:

```
[Test]
public void test123()
{
       string domain = "localhost";
       string userName = "lukk";

       string charactersToCheck = @"¬`!£$%^&*()_+={}[]:;@'~#<>,.?/|\";

       foreach (var character in charactersToCheck.ToCharArray())
       {
              string internalGetPassword = character.ToString();

              try
              {
                     // begin - this assignement was copied from System.Net.BasicClient.Lookup method
                     byte[] inArray = EncodingRightGetBytes(
                           (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain) ? (domain + @"\") : "")
                           + userName
                           + ":"
                           + internalGetPassword);
                     //end
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("this character is bad: {0}", internalGetPassword));
              }
       }
}
```

As you can see EncodingRightGetBytes compares two strings and they are different if the original string (rawString) contains british pound.

EncodingRightGetBytes works fine when I replace the “Encoding.Default.” with “Encoding.UTF8.”…

Googling this method name brings back very few links, one of them being this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943511

I am using VS 2010 with an asp.net project set to use .net 3.5.

So would that be a bug in the .NET framework or am I doing something wrong?

Edit:
When I query the Encoding.Default in the Immediate window while running my test I get this:

```
?Encoding.Default
    {System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding}
    [System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding]: {System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding}
    BodyName: "iso-8859-2"
    CodePage: 1250
    dataItem: {System.Globalization.CodePageDataItem}
    decoderFallback: {System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback}
    DecoderFallback: {System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback}
    EncoderFallback: {System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback}
    encoderFallback: {System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback}
    EncodingName: "Central European (Windows)"
    HeaderName: "windows-1250"
    IsBrowserDisplay: true
    IsBrowserSave: true
    IsMailNewsDisplay: true
    IsMailNewsSave: true
    IsReadOnly: true
    IsSingleByte: true
    m_codePage: 1250
    m_deserializedFromEverett: false
    m_isReadOnly: true
    WebName: "windows-1250"
    WindowsCodePage: 1250
```

Comment: Assuming you're using a british keyboard, what happens if you enter ±, § or € as part of the string (all are found on a UK keyboard)?  If these fail as well, then the issue is definitely with 7 vs 8 bit encoding, as all of these chars have codes above 128 (i.e. use 8 bits) and hence can't be processed correctly with the default encoding, which, most likely, is Latin1 or some variation thereof.  Is there a way to change the encoding to UTF8?

Comment: It does sound like a problem with the pound character being encoded as an 'extended' ASCII character, which can only be made sense of if you know the code page that was used (obviously a password hash would not include the code page used to make it), so the encoding method may be rightly rejecting ambiguously encoded characters. UTF8 sounds like the right solution.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your comments. 

@Aleks - I added these three chars: "±§€" to my test string and they all pass the test. BTW my keyboard is English (Ireland)

Comment: @David - yes, it seems like guys at Microsoft were thinking about it. If you  look at the original source of the method here: http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidEEB268F64CD437C25C0E0547B345284F9E585881.aspx 
you can see that UTF8 is in the comments.

Comment: Ah, they are specifically covering the "every character turns into ?" password bug. A couple of platforms got hit by that since the hashing methods are designed to use unicode, and those ambiguous characters are changed to "?" when converted. Foreign character passwords encoded with the local code page become a string of questions marks - not a hard password for someone to guess. You can see where they check if the password is still the same before and after conversion to proper unicode.

Comment: @David - I think that I understand the need, but would you agree that it doesn't look like using Encoding.Default is the right thing to do if it prevents people from using pound sign in their password? I mean Encoding.Default "Gets an encoding for the operating system's current ANSI code page." In my case it returns a single-byte character set (SBCS) code page (1250), so it restricts me to only using 256 characters from that code page. Shouldnt it use a Unicode encoding system?

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced something similar with asp, I managed to get around the issue by using the following config.

```
<system.web>    
<globalization
 fileEncoding="utf-8"
 requestEncoding="utf-8"      
 responseEncoding="utf-8"
 culture="en-GB"
 uiCulture="en-GB"/>
...
```

To my knowledge the globalization tag works the same for WCF when you set the

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

Update: Just checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738737.aspx) at the bottom of the page it states the following:

> The ASP.NET configuration language allows you to specify the culture
>   for individual services. The WCF does not support that configuration
>   setting except in ASP.NET compatibility mode. To localize a WCF
>   service that does not use ASP.NET compatibility mode, compile the
>   service type into culture-specific assemblies, and have separate
>   culture-specific endpoints for each culture-specific assembly.